# Get field added via attachment_fields_to_edit filter in Gutenberg

Tags: images, filters, block-editor, attachments

In a plugin I'm building, I've added a field named `attribution` to attachments via the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter.

I'm trying to get this info in the block editor but when I output the variable holding the attachments using `console.log`, I only see the following props. This is an example:

```
alt: ""
​​caption: ""
​​id: 25
​​link: "http://example.com/page/1_58image1600x1200/"
​​mime: "image/jpeg"
​​sizes: Object { thumbnail: {…}, medium: {…}, large: {…}, … }
​​subtype: "jpeg"
​​type: "image"
​​url: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/1_58image1600x1200.jpg"
```

Is there a way to get the data from attachment fields added via the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter in Gutenberg?

UPDATE (Adding some code for completeness):

This is the component that opens a window for selecting attachments:

```
<MediaPlaceholder
    accept="image/*"
    allowedTypes={['image']}
    onSelect={setItems}
    multiple={true}
    gallery={true}
    addToGallery={true}
    handleUpload={true}
    labels={
        { title: __('My Gallery') }
    }
/>
```

This is the function that stores the selected attachments in an array attribute named `items`:

```
const setItems = (media) => {
    setAttributes({ items: media })
}
```

This is the function that displays the stored attachments in the `items` attribute:

```
const displayItems = (items) => {
    console.log(items);
    return (
        items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="attachment" key={index}>
                    <figure>
                        <img src={item.url} alt={item.alt} key={item.id} />
                    </figure>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
};
```

The `console.log(items)` call just returns an array of attachments without the custom `attribution` field.

As suggested, I registered the meta field using the `register_post_meta` function in the PHP side with no success:

```
function register_meta_field() {
    register_post_meta(
        'attachment',
        'attribution',
        array(
            'show_in_rest'      => true,
            'type'              => 'string',
            'single'            => true,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'auth_callback'     => function() {
                return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
            },
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_meta_field' );
```

Comment: Have you registered the meta and enable it in the REST API, e.g. by setting `show_in_rest` to `true`?

Comment: If yes, then have you checked whether the meta is showing in the REST API? (E.g. By fetching the data directly from `/wp-json/wp/v2/media/25`) Also, how are you getting the data in the block editor? What's your code?

Comment: @SallyCJ I added some code for completeness.

Comment: @SallyCJ If I call `/wp-json/wp/v2/media` directly, I get ALL the attachment data. It seems that the `MediaPlaceholder` component is the culprit, as it only returns a reduced version of this data with just the main attachment fields.

Comment: @SallyCJ The following function is the culprit: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/388d3d4034ad8f40a5e334d45a4ceab1c7c175d5/packages/media-utils/src/components/media-upload/index.js#L193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right that the [`slimImageObject`  function](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/7e505dc5cd2037eb9fc6730bbd1e0e3846eabef8/packages/media-utils/src/components/media-upload/index.js#L193C22-L193C22) is the reason why you're seeing/getting only those limited list of props.

But don't worry, you can use `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getMedia( <attachment id> )` to get the `attribution` meta (and any other meta or props in the full attachment object). Here's an example that worked for me:

```js
items.map((item, index) => {
    // Add this line and the attribution part in the attachment div.
    const attribution = wp.data.select( 'core' ).getMedia( item.id )?.meta?.attribution;

    return (
        <div className="attachment" key={index}>
            <figure>
                <img src={item.url} alt={item.alt} key={item.id} />
            </figure>
            Attribution: { attribution || 'NA' }
        </div>
    )
})
```

Comment: PS: You can instead add `import { select } from '@wordpress/data';` at the top in your file, and use `select( 'core' )` instead of `wp.data.select( 'core' )`.